# $x>0$, $y>0$, To prove $x^y > \frac{x}{x+y}$

Tags: inequality

About any positive real ''$y$''

When   $x>1$    it is trivial.

But  $0 < x < 1$ , 
about any positive real ''$y$''

$x^{y} > \frac{x}{x+y}$

is true ?

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to $y\ln x>\ln x-\ln(x+y)$. Try to study function $f:x\mapsto (y-1)\ln x+\ln(x+y)$. You'll have to consider two cases : $0<y<1$ and $y\ge1$.

Comment: I think that some x in (0,1) exist then f(x) <0  , when y>1  ?

Comment: Yup, I think you're right, as $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)=-\infty$ ! My bad...

Answer (score 1):

Is the following inequality true?

$$\left(1\over2\right)^3\gt{{1\over2}\over{1\over2}+3}$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that in the only case :  y in (y>1) and x in (0,1) the inequality is false ?